# openpyxl for loop - increment the value

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to set values in an excel sheet using a for loop but i'm a little stuck. It should set A1 - A4 as the items in the list. My code kicks back an error when I try to increment A1 in the for loop:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('morning.xlsx')
am_sheet = wb.active

list1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'bear', 'mouse']

i = 1

for x in list1:
    am_sheet['%s'].value = x % ("A" + str(i))
    i += 1
```

The error kicks back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Pyjects/am/twinder.py", line 11, in <module>
   am_sheet['%s'].value = x % ("A" + str(i))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`am_sheet['%s'].value = x % ("A" + str(i))`

The interpolation syntax should be immediately after the string literal:

`am_sheet['%s' % ("A" + str(i))].value = x`

but you can use the much cleaner `.format`:

`am_sheet['A{}'.format(i)].value = x`

Comment: That'll do it - appreciate the help Deep!

Comment: Use of programmatic indexing of worksheets should be avoided, see my answer for a simple and more reliable approach.

Comment: @CharlieClark, While I agree that your answer may be more efficient, especially in time of converting- one benefit to this approach is if your are trying to explain your code to non-python users. Using `A1` coordinates really helps people understand what is happening. It removes the end user to have to translate row,column indexing to `A1` notation in their. Because heavy excel users often used Named Ranges and this can certainly help them as well.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ws['A%s' % (i)]` in any code. Use the worksheet's `.cell()` method instead: `ws.cell(row=i, column=1)`

Comment: Thanks Charlie - Any particular reason why it should be avoided?

Comment: Because you will almost always have a numerical index you want to use. Pointless to waste time converting this to `A1` coordinates when you don't need to.